# How to add tap to play/pause to a VideoView?

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I'm trying to add video play/pause functionality into a chat that I'm making, so I have a standard:

```
VideoView vidRight;
vidRight = v.findViewById(R.id.videoViewRight);
```

However, trying to add a tap to play/pause with a listener is not possible as I would need to declare `paused` final:

```
boolean paused = false;
vidRight.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (paused) {
            vidRight.start();
            paused = false;
        }
        else {
            vidRight.stopPlayback();
            paused = true;
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Make `paused` a member variable.

Comment: @MalaKa wouldn't I have to make `vidRight` a member variable too then? In my case it would not be possible.

Comment: No, from what you posted, I don't think so. If you don't override the `vidRight` variable, it is effectively final (which is sufficient in java 8). But you do override the value of paused. So you need to make it a member variable.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to maintain a custom flag `paused` for checking the state. Instead you can use `isPlaying` to check if the video is currently playing or not.

```
vidRight.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (vidRight.isPlaying()) {
            vidRight.stopPlayback();
         }
         else {
            vidRight.start();
         }

         return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Declare the "paused" variable as a member variable just like this:

```java
public class YourClassName extends AppCompatActivity implements YourInterfaces {
    private boolean paused=false;
    /* your other variables */
      @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        vidRight.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (paused) {
                        vidRight.start();
                        paused = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        vidRight.stopPlayback();
                        paused = true;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to handle this by implementing this code:

```
 if (videoView.isPlaying()) {
        videoView.pause();
     } else {
        videoView.start();         
     }
```

I hope this will be usefull for someone.